# How to run these 2 commands together in python?

Tags: python, ipython

I have this code in Spyder (Python 3.7):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#%% Práctica 1 
%reset -f
plt.close("all")
```

If I only run one of the commands (any of them) works well, but I can't run both of them at the same time (Then, I get the error `name 'plt' is not defined` althought I have run the import command). I don't have any clue about what can happen.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Which command works?

Comment: Both, but only if I run one each time

Comment: Can you split the commands up so I can see what you mean? How do you run them?

Comment: What error do you get ? What have you tried ? What are you trying to do? and what would be your expected output? Please, edit your question so we can 
 have more information to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of commands:

```
%reset -f

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!